# Get shopify analytics token programmatically

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

How do you get the token needed to make a request to the Shopify analytics API?

For example:

```
POST https://analytics.shopify.com/queries?beta=true

REQUEST BODY:
token: HOW_DO_I_GET_THIS?
q[]: SHOW+total_visitors+AS+%22total_visitors...
source: shopify-reports
```

I've tried using OAuth, but it seems to be a different token entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You have to request Shopify Core GraphQL to get analyticsToken.

```
POST /admin/internal/web/graphql/core HTTP/1.1
Host: [[STORE_NAME]].myshopify.com
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-CA,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
content-type: application/json
X-CSRF-Token: [[CSRF_TOKEN]]
Origin: https://[[STORE_NAME]].myshopify.com
Connection: close
Cookie: [[COOKIE]]

{ "query": "{ shop { analyticsToken } }" }
```

Since the request requires CSRF Token & Cookie, it's not programmatic at all.

For additional information please check the [Examples for Testing in the Shopify Admin](https://github.com/Shopify/bugbounty-resources/blob/master/graphql/testing_with_burp.md#crafting-a-query) page.